# Combinatory logic library for proof assistants?

Tags: coq, theorem-proving, combinatory-logic

I'm working through some intro-level combinatory logic exercises using Coq. I've written a crude library for it, but it isn't very efficient. Is there a combinatory logic library for Coq or other proof assistants? Definitions of combinators, terms & their relations along with proofs of some important theorems would be quite helpful.

There is a [discussion about Agda and combinatory logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406786/what-is-the-combinatory-logic-equivalent-of-intuitionistic-type-theory) that looks interesting, but I can't tell whether it is relevant for my question.

Comment: I doubt this is helpful, but I like using JavaScript to implement lambda logic.